# Superscript in Document Title with ACM

Tags: titles, superscripts, acm

I'm trying to get a superscript into the title of my paper using ACM's template.  I'm having an issue in that when I try to set the text as a superscript, it ends up in a small font, not scaled with the title, and in the center of the line.

Here's a working example:

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\title{DT\textsuperscript{2}CE}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Not sure how I can correct this.  I've tried using `\raise0.5ex\hbox{2}` but that doesn't scale the text to size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To typeset the title, the class `acm_proc_article-sp` uses `\ttlfnt` which is defined using the problematic old `\newfont` (in fact, it uses this old command for other elements too!):

```
\newfont{\ttlfnt}{phvb8t at 18pt}
```

Give a sensible replacement definition such as

```
\renewcommand\ttlfnt{\fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{18}{22}\selectfont}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}

\renewcommand\ttlfnt{\fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{18}{22}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\title{DT{\fontsize{17.28}{20}\selectfont\textsuperscript{2}}CE}
\author{Author}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Chance You're welcome. I updated my answer with an addition to provent a font substitution with the superscript font.